# PHP gmail IMAP stopped working

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I found an example to fetch emails from Gmail few months ago. Everything was working, but suddenly (maybe on Monday) it stopped working. When I execute this script - it simply freezes (infinity loading) and doesn't give any error to the screen.

Everything was working last week, but suddenly - issues appeared.

PHP Code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gma$

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

foreach($emails as $email_number) { /* do smth */ }
```

Maybe somebody got the same problem with Gmail & IMAP?

IMAP is enabled in Gmail. Checked it twice.

I just checked apache logs and found error: "IMAP connection lost". That's all, no more information about error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
<?php
    /* connect to gmail */
 $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail';
    $username = 'hidden';
    $password = 'hidden';

    /* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

      /* begin output var */
      $output = '';

      /* put the newest emails on top */
      rsort($emails);

      /* for every email... */
      foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
      }

      echo $output;
    } 

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);
    ?>
```

Comment: Your provided example doesn't work (works like mine). It loads veeerrryyy long and doesn't give any response at all, please check it in your server. I have just checked apache logs and found an error: "IMAP connection lost". That's all...